# How to write to common chat in Heroes of the storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Is it possible to write to the common chat during Heroes of the storm game?

'Enter' gives me allies chat only, 'Cmd+Enter', 'Alt+Enter' (on Mac) don't help either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just can't, it is not implemented.

At the end of the game, you can say "gg", it's the only word you can say in all chat and only at the end of the game. 
As @Xrylite said, it is an automatic trigger, and it works even if the game says [Allies].

Also, always at the end, your emotes will be visible to everyone ( press y or z to use the emotes )

In short, the only visible messages are emotes, and "gg" only at the end of the game.

Bonus: while writing in chat you can press Tab to speak only with your party or friend.

Comment: Ok. How can I say gg to all chat if whatever i press it proposes me to write to allies only.

Comment: @klm123 The map automatically sends it to everyone even though that says '[Allies]'. It's just a simple trigger so that people don't think they can type other things to each other.

Comment: @Xrylite, thank you. **Jubatus**, I accept your answer, but I don't think it is full without what Xrylite wrote, please add this to your answer.

Comment: Made a small edit to quote @Xrylite

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer is still relevant, but in quickmatch, unranked, ranked or brawl, it is not possible yet.

The only games where you can "all chat" is in custom games (lobby)

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you see the chat input, and then you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly until you see "[All]" at the beginning of the input

Comment: I'm not familiar with this game. Does this answer add anything to the already accepted one?

Comment: @Fabian well, this is the only known way to chat with your opponents ingame, pre-made opponents in the same lobby, so you basically know each other, and no risk of pure offense is present